# ng-bootstrap Modal border-radius

Tags: html, css, ng-bootstrap

**What is the best way to customize the border-radius of the NgBoostrap modal?**

```html
<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Test</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Hello, World!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('Save click')">Save</button>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Hi Soury we don't add SOLVED to the title on SO, instead you mark the answer that solved the problem with the green check. Try it out!. When done you can also flag this comment as no longer needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `border-radius` to `modal-content` class:

```
.modal-content{
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I already did that, but he doesn't find the class in html

Answer (score 1):

***I went to my component's typescript and put this:***

```
this.modalService.open(content, {centered: true, windowClass: 'modal-rounded', size: 'lg'});
```

***Soon after I went to my main scss (styles.scss) and put this code there:***

```
.modal-rounded {
    .modal-content {
      border-radius: 20px !important;
    }
  }
```